# Is it possible to modify an existing AMI to change delete on termination settings on the EBS volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several AMIs that developers use to spin up instances.  These AMI do not have "delete on termination" set on all their EBS volumes.  At times terminating instances launched using these AMIs has the unintended consequence of leaving behind orphan EBS volumes.  Unfortunately, "blessing" a new AMI for general use is quite an ordeal.  Is it possible to edit an existing AMI to turn on "delete on termination" or is the only way forward to create a new AMI with the proper settings?

Comment: Since AMI is launch information + snapshot, so you can simply create AMI from snapshot, and during this step, you can redefine the "deleteOnTerminate" attribute, EBS size and even change the default gp2 volume type to gp3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the "Delete on termination" value on an existing AMI.

So you have 2 choices:

1. Launch an EC2 instance from your AMI and produce a new AMI with the appropriate "Delete on Terminate" value, or
2. Modify the value when you launch the new EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  This is what I suspected.  I hope others with the same question can now find this online.

Answer (score 7):

Once the instance is running you can call modifyAttribute (modify-instance-attribute  in the CLI) on the attribute blockDeviceMapping.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-a3ef245 --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sda\",\"Ebs\":{\"DeleteOnTermination\":false}}]"
```

You can see an example here: http://www.petewilcock.com/how-to-modify-deletion-on-termination-flag-for-ebs-volume-on-running-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such features.

In addition, I think you misundestand the purpose of AWS web console EC2 EBS Volumes vs snapshot.

When you launch an instances, a EBS Volume is assign to the instance(if it is a EBS base instance like t2.*, c3.*) , once you terminate it, that assoicated volume will be deleted.
**Unless you create a EBS volumes that attach to a instances**, that is another story. An attached volumes will stay even the instance it attached to is deleted, this is intended design as EBS volumes is network storage anyway, it should allow you to detach/attach to different instances dynamically.

On the other hand, your user may create **snapshot(s)** for their instances, which store under the Snapshot portion. This is part that will stay, even you terminate the original instance. Once you deleted the original instance, the volume it point do will be "orphaned".

It is a good practice to create a snapshot for instance as backup, but it will go wilds if you don't have a standard policy to handle it. No automation can help a process nature issues.

You MUST enforce a policy and standard for your developer to follow as well, e.g. backup cycle, tag for snapshot, etc.

Comment: Root EBS volumes are not automatically set to "Delete on Terminate". For all EBS volumes created with an EC2 instance, that setting is determined by the value saved in the AMI, for root volumes or extra volumes. Look at the "Block Devices" value on an AMI. Within it, you'll see `true` or `false`. That is the "Delete on Terminate" value. Amazon has configured their default AMI images with a "true" value. The OP is saying that value is "false" in their current AMI.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. My oversight. I always launch instance from general  AMI stores that seems already set the bit on. This seems handy if I need to regularly create updated AMI to launch spot instances.